# Client components, localstorage in nextjs13

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I am moving the project from react to nextjs and have a problem. I have a global wrapper that handles the login context and is using local storage.
I set **"use client"** directive at the top, but the component is trying to be rendered on the server too, and this code gives a hydration error:

```
export function AuthProvider(props) {
  
  const initialParsedToken =  typeof localStorage !== 'undefined' ? localStorage.getItem("jwt") : null

  if (initialParsedToken) {
    const decodedToken = jwtDecode<JwtInterface>(initialParsedToken);

    if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
    } else {
      initialState.user = decodedToken;
    }
  }

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, initialState);

  if (typeof localStorage === 'undefined'){
    return null
  }

  const login = (userData: any) => {
    localStorage.setItem("jwt", userData.token);
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", payload: userData });
  };

  function logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem("jwt");
    dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
  }

  return (
      <AuthContext.Provider
          value={{ user: state.user, login, logout }}
          {...props}
      />
  );
}
```

The error:

```
    Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
```

How can i use the **useReducer** hook in next, or make auth logic work with this framework?

I was planning to make render static content as server components, having client parts, but can I avoid using ugly useffect hack in each client component and just add a **use client** in nested dynamic content?

I tried using useffect hack in parent component, but nested components still don't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check on the type of window instead to make sure you are on the client side

```
if (typeof window !== undefined){
....your local storage logic
}
```

Also, you should consider moving your token to cookies instead of local storage as it doesn't cause conflicts and you can check your cookies on the server side using the context parameter, see [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)

Comment: Thanks for info, isn't this behaviour unexpected with "use-client" directive? I have suspicion that use-client isn't purely client rendered and there is some magic partial prerender, if that is the case, that would explain this behaviour.

Comment: Your cache solution did work, in react 13 i had to also use router.refresh() for my layout to react on cookie change.

Comment: You are right, they still have issues with local storage even with use-client directive. This will be fixed in the future as stated by Vercel.

Comment: @Martinn3 you're correct. `use-client` just make the component into client component. And client component does not mean that it renders on client completely. Client component is itself rendered in server at first. You can find more details in this series: https://dev.to/peterlidee/a-deep-dive-into-client-and-server-component-versus-static-and-dynamic-rendering-in-next-13-intro-1mbo

Answer (score 1):

According to [the NextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#client-components),

> Client Components enable you to add client-side interactivity to your application. In Next.js, they are pre-rendered on the server and hydrated on the client.

So yes, they are rendered on the server first. You can use `useState` to check if the component is mounted:

```
"use client";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Page() {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false); // used for detecting renders

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []); // runs once on component mount

  if (!mounted) {
    return <> </>
  }
  return <div>Your page</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete the accepted answer, the right code would actually be:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined'){
....your local storage logic
}
```

As typeof returns a string.